# How to debug firefox plugin?

Tags: firefox, debugging, plugins

I'm writing plugin for firefox and I need a way to debug it. Plugin written in javascript.
So is there is a elegant way how I can debug it?

**Update 2014: There's a [builtin Firefox debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17579253/1168315)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Venkman's Javascript Debugger](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/venkman/).

Answer (score 3):

The [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/) has plenty of useful information on this topic (as well as many others).

I would recommend [*Setting up an extension development environment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_up_extension_development_environment) as a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

[Chromebug](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Chromebug_User_Guide) is a useful tool which allows JavaScript debugging and inspecting XUL elements. You can take a look at a few screenshots  [here](http://whilefreelancing.blogspot.com/2011/02/debugging-firefox-add-ons-using.html).