# How to debug a Firefox extension with Chromebug?

Tags: debugging, firefox, plugins, firefox-addon, chromebug

I'm trying to debug my Firefox add-on with Chromebug, but I can't see the error trace or log trace.  I've configured a dedicated profile and set `about:config` parameters according to [this Mozilla tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_up_extension_development_environment). I've installed Firebug and Chromebug with the same version (1.7.2) But when I execute one of my extension "action" with "error thrower" code, nothing happened. No log, no trace.

In Chromebug, the file list is empty. I read in multiple discussions on the web that I should see a list of debuggable scripts.

A screenshot of my environment:

[image: screenshot of my environment]

What else must I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update April 2014: The browser debugger is now integrated in the "Browser Toolbox" and you no longer need to set about:config prefs. Just use the developer tools configuration/settings panel: "enable chrome debugging" and "enable remote debugging". The "Browser Toolbox" will then be available in the developer tools panel.**

Chromebug has not worked for me for many months. I think it's just been silently abandoned but thankfully on Firefox 19 or later, it's possible to use the built-in JS debugger on the browser itself.  Go to about:config and set the following two prefs:

```
devtools.chrome.enabled: true
devtools.debugger.remote-enabled: true
```

After you restart the browser, the Web Developer menu will contain a "Browser Debugger" entry.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_JavaScript

If possible, I'd suggest using Aurora for your debugging because the built-in debugger was a little limited when first launched and keeps getting better with every release.

Comment: It's perfect ! Thank's !

Comment: what's the difference between Aurora and FF? Why Aurora is better?

Comment: @SharonHaimPour Aurora ≃ Firefox alpha. Every six weeks a new Aurora version is released, the previous Aurora version moves to beta and the previous beta version is delivered to all stable users. You can get more info here: http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/#aurora

Comment: But why it's better for debugging? Does it have a better debugging tool?

Comment: @SharonHaimPour Yes, in every new release it's becoming better and with more features.

Comment: @Aljullu - I couldn't see why it's better. Can you explain?

Comment: @SharonHaimPour What is new in Firefox 25 and Firefox 26 devtools:
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/08/new-features-of-firefox-developer-tools-episode-25/
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/09/new-features-in-the-firefox-developer-tools-episode-26/ Hope it helps. ;-)

Comment: You don't even have to go find those entries in about:config anymore, they are in the settings gear tab of the Firefox Web Developer tools.